# Is there a way to simplify $\sum_{j=0}^{n}C_{n}^{j}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\frac{j}{j+i}C_{m}^{i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way to simplify the following sequence?
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n}C_{n}^{j}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\frac{j}{j+i}C_{m}^{i}
$$

Comment: The $i=j=0$ term is undefined. (And the notation for binomial coefficients is unusual, assuming that your $C_m^i$ is $\binom{m}i$.)

Comment: This was nearly the only notation in use in some countries until semi-recently.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This was the usual notation in France around 15 years ago, and it probably still is in other countries in continental Europe. Nowadays it's beeing replaced by the english notation with parens.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: one might as well start the first sum from $j=1$, because of the factor $j$ in the summand; then dividing by $j+i$ is uncontroversial.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: What surprised me was the order of the indices: I’ve seen $C_i^m$ for $\binom{m}i$ fairly often, but $C_m^i$ only a few times — all here, I think.

Comment: @Greg: Agreed; I just wondered whether the OP would notice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Actually, it's usually reversed, so $C_n^p={n \choose p}$. I have never seen $C_p^n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott,@Did: I am from China and $C_{m}^{i}$ is the notation used in mathematical education in China.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: I assumed from your previous comment that you meant the OP’s version, and I wasn’t doubting you; when you mentioned it, I even recalled having learned that before. I meant that in U.S. usage I’ve seen $C_i^m$ significantly more often than $C_m^i$. I didn’t know, however, that $C_m^i$ was normal in Chinese usage until the OP mentioned it just now.

Comment: @handsomeyang I have no problem with the notation $C_m^i$ (and I never saw the notation $C_i^m$ except in some confused math.se questions).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$j{n\choose j}=n{n-1\choose j-1},\qquad \frac1k=\int_0^1x^{k-1}\mathrm dx,$$ for every $k\geqslant1$, hence the sum in the question is $$n\sum_{i,j}{n-1\choose j-1}{m\choose i}\int_0^1x^{j+i-1}\,\mathrm dx=n\int_0^1\sum_j{n-1\choose j-1}x^{j-1}\cdot\sum_i{m\choose i}x^i\,\mathrm dx,$$ that is, $$n\int_0^1(1+x)^{n-1}\cdot(1+x)^m\,\mathrm dx=\frac{n}{n+m}\left.(1+x)^{n+m}\right|_0^1=\frac{n}{n+m}(2^{n+m}-1).$$

Comment: Thanks. $\frac{n}{n+m}(2^{n+m}-1)$ is exactly the kind of answer I was expecting. I will work on and verify the derivation.